# Emulators not working in SeeTest

Tags: qtp, automated-tests, testcomplete

while i used Android Emulators to work in seetest, few emulators are workng great but not all ...... Why is this happening,

1. few emulators are not yet all opening,
2. few are not able to launch the application .... please do help me
   out .
3. i have gone through experitest there is not much information abt
   work with emulators ..
4. when try to launch emulator it is showing the error as if this ....

**emulator.exe stooped executing**

Comment: Welcome. This is not a general Q&A site, it is specific to programming-specific topics. Usually, you´d specify some problem in a piece of source code. There is no source code in your question, and no programming-specific aspect, is there? Please rethink/edit your question. And read the SO FAQs.

Answer (score 0):

Some emulator's images can have low performance when working with SeeTest .
It is recommended to configure the Virtual Machine Acceleration to improve the emulator performance.
You can use this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm
More details can be found in here:
http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/Connect_Android_emulator.htm